# NSSegmentedControl segments selectable event though disabled

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nssegmentedcontrol

I have a `NSSegmentedControl` in a toolbar. Its mode is set to "**momentary**" because the segments should appear to work like buttons, not like permanent selections.

The rules for enabling:

- When content is selected, all 3 segments should be enabled.
- When no content is selected, only the last one should be enabled.

So I cannot disable the whole control but only some segments.

```
let enabled = hasSelection()

AddDimensionSegmentedControl.contextualSegments // = (0...1)
    .forEach { (segment: Int) in
        self.setEnabled(enabled, forSegment: segment)
}
```

That works quite well so far:

[image: disabling works]

But I can still click on disabled segments and have them selected even though that's not the selection mode

[image]

What I tried:

- when the selection changes, deselect the segment again
- when the toolbar validates, set `selectedSegment = -1`

Still the disabled-looking selection stays in tact. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Someone pointed out something in a chat, and here's the solution I found: you have to disable *both* the `NSToolbarItem` that represents the segment and the segment itself.

If you only have 1 `NSToolbarItem` that contains the `NSSegmentedControl` instead of a `NSToolbarItemGroup`, you maybe don't have to do that.